# If/Else statement for localStorage?

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to make an If/Else statement with localStorage but run into problems.
I can't seem to link the If-statement to my localStorage User(s) and always get the Else-statement.
How do i iterate through the localStorage keys and get the value of the user(s)?

***It would make sense to me if i could somehow target ID 1, ID 2, ID 3 etc. but how?***

**Code for IF/ELSE:**

```
User.$button_login.addEventListener("click", function(entry) {

    for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i) {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));

    }

    if (document.getElementById("firstName").value == User.$form.user_name.value) {
        if (document.getElementById("passWord").value == User.$form.password.value) {
            alert("You have logged in");
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("negative").innerHTML = "Username or Password does not match"
    }


}, true);


},
```

**Code for User(s):**

```
var User = {
    index: window.localStorage.getItem("User:index"),
    $form: document.getElementById("userReg"),


    $button_register: document.getElementById("registerUser"),
    $button_login: document.getElementById("logIN"),

    init: function() {
        // initialize storage index
        if (!User.index) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("User:index", User.index = 1);
        }

        User.$form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            var entry = {
                id: parseInt(this.id_entry.value),
                user_name: this.user_name.value,
                password: this.password.value
            };
            if (entry.id == 0) {
                User.storeAdd(entry);
            }
        }, true);

storeAdd: function(entry) {
        entry.id = User.index;
        window.localStorage.setItem("User:index", ++User.index);
        window.localStorage.setItem("User:" + entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
    },
};
```

Comment: Very bad idea to do a login like that; should always check server-side. May be you can do a "remember me" functionality with localstorage but not if (document.getElementById("passWord").value == User.$form.password.value) then "you're logged in"

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you are trying to do with that code.

Comment: @Hanshof: When you are constructing your `entry` object, what are this.id_entry, this.user_name, and this.password supposed to be?

Comment: I am asking what those values are supposed to be. I don't see where they come from.

Comment: But I can check my console with the code: console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))); where i get the localStorage information from entries (value) and the key (User:1, User:2 etc..) how do i target each key for each value?

Comment: @Hanshof: What does "target each key for each value" mean?

Comment: @76484 if you debug localStorage in Chrome>Resources you have a key and a value set.. and if i check my localStorage value I get the object [id:1, user_name: user1, password:pass1].. so how do i target a specific value e.g. "user1" or "pass1"?

Comment: You need to parse the string of JSON data so that you have a plain old JavaScript object to work with: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Cool thanks! I can see in my console that is has changed to a javaScript object with the code var entry = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))); ...gives me something to work on;)

Comment: But if i check console.log(entry.user_name); i get the three user_name i have registered, but i also get a "undefined".. why is that?

Comment: @Hanshof: You are getting 'undefined' because in your localStorage items loop is the 'User:index' key whose value is an integer - so it does not have a 'user_name' property.

Comment: @Hanshof: I think you will have an easier time if, instead of storing each user as an individual record in localStorage, you store a *single* users record which contains an array of all users. I have created a fiddle with a `Users` object that manages the fetching and saving to localStorage: http://jsfiddle.net/76484/064vg6un/1/